# Ad-Hoc deployment: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone, deployment, adhoc

I try to install an application using ad-hoc deployment and I get the following error: "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements."

I use Xcode 4.2. As far as I know I don't need to create a entitlements.plist file anymore. Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entitlements.plist is not needed. But I created a new code signement "Deployment" add added the Deployment Profile to it.